# NSBundle from my library is nil

Tags: bundle, iso

I created my own iOS library with core data inside,
as suggested [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/08/25/sharing-a-core-data-model-with-a-swift-framework/).

I added library to my project and build is success, but when I am trying to load the database:
`bundleWithIdentifier` method for my bundle `return`s `nil`.

```
NSBundle * testBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"result.BIModel"];
// testBundle = nil;
```

My library's bundle identifier is set(see image below), I added the framework to "Link Binary With Libraries" and "Embed Frameworks".

[image]

What am I missing ?

EDIT :

I notice that when framework is created one file is missing.

I build test framework (that works and `bundleWithIdentifier` return bundle) and get [image: this] (see last file),

but when I build my framework i get

[image: this]. See that last file is missing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you mean that if I add Post-actions for building library, yes I did.

Comment: Yeah sorry, you mentioned that you set it in to "Link Binary With ..." I have missed it when I read for the first time

Comment: @user3351949 can you see my edit? Because I thing this is a reason for this...

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to help you :-( i can only suggest to check in build phase of the framework that you are exporting an copying everything.